# How to disable public ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, openvpn

I would like to disable public access to ssh. How do I still access the server but block port 22? Do I need to create another instance just for openvpn (which is fine)? Is there a tutorial somewhere to basically "hide" ssh behind a vpn?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on why you want to block port 22, it might just be good enough to move your sshd from port 22 to any other port, like 22222 or 12345. This is accomplished by adding a line

```
Port 12345
```

to /etc/ssh/sshd_config and reloading sshd config like

```
/etc/init.d/ssh reload
```

You can have more than one active port, just by more than one such port line in the config file.

TomTomTom

Comment: If the requirement is really to block port 22, then this answer is useful. If it is to block out ssh from being publicly visible, then not as much.

Comment: Changing the SSH port on a server is almost useless these days. Port scanning is absolutely rife, and there are API's that will literally tell you what port is running SSH on a server.

Answer (score 1):

If your server has a vpn connection, perhaps you can set your ssh's server *ListenAddress* to the local vpn endpoint, instead of the default of all local addresses.

Comment: Could you explain this setup in further detail? Do I just install openvpn onto the webserver and do this all on one box? Or do I need another server with openvpn on it separately?

Comment: I thought from your question that you already had a vpn set up on the server. In any case it has to be set up between 2 computers, so your setup would either be: 1) vpn between your own computer/network and the server, and sshd listens on the address of the created *tun* device; or 2) your server is in a private network which you have vpn access to, and so public access is blocked by design.

Answer (score 1):

I have a `Debian 8` server with a public ip and block and open access when I want using `knockd`:

```
apt-get install -y knockd
```

In the configuration file `/etc/knockd.conf`:

```
[options]
    UseSyslog

[openSSH]
    sequence    = 2009,8019,9099
    seq_timeout = 20
    command     = /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn

[closeSSH]
    sequence    = 2000,1449,6712
    seq_timeout = 20
    command     = /sbin/iptables -D INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    tcpflags    = syn
```

Now you need to restart the service with `/etc/init.d/knockd restart`

To open and close the ssh port, I have one script in my pc:

Open

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

for i in 2009 8019 9099
do
  nmap -Pn -p ${i} --max-retries 0 myremoteserverip
done
```

Close

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin

for i in 2000 1449 6712
do
  nmap -Pn -p ${i} --max-retries 0 myremoteserverip
done
```

Now, the last step is block all incoming traffic with  `iptables -P INPUT DROP`

At this point, you can try to open ssh port, using the script, do this, if you have console to get inside your server if you block out.

Comment: +1. Port Knocking is a fantastic way to secure your SSH ports. @op it's basically a secret knock for the door to your SSH. The port will stay closed until the correct sequence of ports has been knocked on.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you want to do.

1. if you just need to disable ssh and connect to you server, just stop sshd and use **telnet** or something else.
2. for the safe concern, vpn wrapped ssh communication, which means ssh is not public, unless vpn is not safe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a static IP you're connecting from? Maybe just allow SSH from that. Otherwise the VPN is an option as well. I myself disallow password authentication. The risks of someone having my 4096 bit private RSA key are pretty minimal.

Answer (score 0):

To change the SSH port, you can change the Port directive on /etc/init.d/sshd_config. Change the default 22 for anything else, and restart the sshd daemon.

If you have a VPN service configured on your server, you can make SSH listen only to the VPN interface.

Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and add this directive (assuming the VPN IP address for the server is 102.168.10.1):

`ListenAddress 192.168.10.1`

Restart ssh (`service sshd restart` or `service ssh restart`, depending on your distribution) and ssh will only be accessible from inside the VPN.